# Best practise for passing data to subview codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, templates

I am looking for the best practise when it comes to passing data from the controller to a subview in Codeigniter, so far I have created a layout file which loads the subviews. For example, when I have been doing this, it does work but I am wondering if there is a cleaner way of doing things? Or are there any better options for templating my html and CSS without having to do this for every function?

Currently renaming each separate $data variable to $var1, $var2, $var3 etc.

Here is my code when loading pagination and passing this to the subview.

```
function index($start=0)
{
    $var1['posts']=$this->post->get_posts(3,$start);
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url']=base_url().'posts/index/';
    $config['total_rows']=$this->post->get_posts_count();
    $config['per_page']=3;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $var2['pages']= $this->pagination->create_links();
    $var3=array('subview' => 'post_index');

    $data=array_merge($var1, $var2, $var3);

    $this->load->view('layouts/layout',$data);  
}
```

And in my template file I use this line of code in the body to load the subviews:

```
<?php $this->load->view($subview); ?>
```

Comment: what is ` $var3=array('subview' => 'post_index');` for?

Comment: post_index is the name of the subview, which lists all the posts in a blog. This line of code places this subview inside the body of the layout by assigning the 'subview' to be the the post index. In each page it would be used like:

$var3=array('subview' => 'login form');`
$var3=array('subview' => 'products_index');`

Answer (score 2):

Okay there indeed is a way to do that. Assuming you have a view called `post_index` in which you pass `$var['posts']` and then you want to put that view in your master layout.

```
$var['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts(3, $start);

// setting the third parameter as true would return the view as 
// data which you can pass to another view
$data['page'] = $this->load->view('post_index', $var, TRUE);
$this->load->view('layouts/layout', $data);
```

From codeigniter docs

> **Returning views as data**
>
> There is a third optional parameter lets you
> change the behavior of the method so that it returns data as a string
> rather than sending it to your browser. This can be useful if you want
> to process the data in some way. If you set the parameter to TRUE
> (boolean) it will return data. The default behavior is false, which
> sends it to your browser. Remember to assign it to a variable if you
> want the data returned.